# Function call triggered automatically when changing index in a ComboBox VB.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, indexing

Alright, So im working on a faily good sized program and im wanting to add a new feature but am unable to even get started. I'm in a windows form in visual basic .net and basically, I have a combobox with 3 items in the drop down menu. I would like to make it to where the moment one of the items in the combo box are selected, the program recognizes the change of index and automatically calls to the function of my choice. I just need help with the concept and a kick in the right direction, not so much an exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is something like this in the "code behind" for the form:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' DO STUFF HERE
End Sub
```